# Fragment to Activity communication via anonymous interface

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, interface

Is this possible? I have been using the standard way of Fragment-Activity communication with onAttach() and am wondering if something like this can be done:

**MainActivity.java**

```
// Create Dialog passing in callback
MyDialogFragment dialog = MyDialogFragment.newInstance(param, new MyDialogInterface) {
        @Override
        public void onSelected(DialogFragment dialog, String result) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onNotSelected(DialogFragment dialog) {

        }
    }
```

**MyDialogFragment.java**

```
// Execute callback
builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                myInterface.onNotSelected(MyDialogFragment.this);
            }
        })
        .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                myInterface.onSelected(MyDialogFragment.this, "WORKED");
            }
        });
```

This would allow me to maintain a linear flow of logic in the code where the Dialog is shown as opposed to having to add additional interface methods to the Activity.

Answer (score 1):

This could be a great solution, but since `Activity` and `Fragment` can be destroyed and re-created from a saved state, this scheme is not reliable - after `Fragment`'s re-creation there will be no reference to the callback inside the `Fragment`.

The standard scheme, involving casting of `Activity` into callback interface in `onAttach()`, should be used because `onAttach()` is guaranteed to be called after `Fragment`'s re-creation with non-null reference to enclosing `Activity`. This is very inconvenient, but this is the limitation imposed by the Android Framework itself.

**Workaround not involving interfaces and casting:**

I tried many variations of "interface-and-casting" approach that you'd like to avoid, and all of them indeed felt dirty and cumbersome, therefore, nowadays, I use [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) in order to support `Fragment`-to-`Activity` communication. The general scheme is something like this (only relevant parts shown):

Activity:

```
public class DemoActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
    }

    @Subscribe
    public void onDemoFragmentEvent(DemoFragment.DemoFragmentCallbackEvent event) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Event in Fragment happened: " + event.getWhatHappened(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Fragment:

```
public class DemoFragment extends Fragment {

    /**
     * Objects of this class will be posted on EventBus if anything happens in this Fragment
     */
    public static class DemoFragmentCallbackEvent {

        private String mWhatHappened;

        public DemoFragmentCallbackEvent(String whatHappened) {
            mWhatHappened = whatHappened;
        }

        public String getWhatHappened() {
            return mWhatHappened;
        }
    }

    public void somethingHappened() {
        EventBus.getDefault().post(new DemoFragmentCallbackEvent("no interfaces and casting"));
    }

}
```

Comment: Had a feeling that would be the case. Was wondering if there was some clever hack somebody could come up with. Would be very convenient!

Comment: @Ron, if you are open for "clever hacks", then you might want to try the approach I use which involves EventBus. See the edited answer.